# Selenium Webdriver takes more than a minute to launch FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver 2.5.3.1 to run my tests on Firefox 39.0 (Firefox Updates turned off).  The below code was working exceptionally well until yesterday.

```
public class Open_Firefox {
    static WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void main(String args[]){
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Today, all of a sudden the above code is taking more than a minute to open Firefox.

I am very new to Selenium, I do not understand why this is happening.
I have not made any changes to firefox in fact I have turned off auto updates.  Please help, thank you.

Comment: may be you have too many processes running on your machine.

Comment: No I have just eclipse and a browser running....Will un-installing and re-installing of Firefox be of any help ?????

Comment: 1) I think you are using 2.53.1 - not 2.5.3.1 2) Is the page quicker, if you load it without Selenium? 3) When Selenium opens the browser click on it and press F12 to toggle the browser console, open network tab and see what network traffic there is.

Comment: I am using 2.53.1 and for the 2nd question launching firefox browser takes lot of time(more than a minute) once the browser is launched page load is faster

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the browser cache, cookies and history. Also delete the system temporary files.

To Delete the System temporary files,

1, Press Windows button + R

2, In the Run Window Enter %temp%

3, Delete all the files that is inside the folder opened.

Comment: Are you using linux/windows? Whats your machine processor and Ram ?

Comment: I am Using Windows, today while executing the test scripts I encountered the beloe error:"org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms."

Comment: This problem can resolved by moving from Selenium 2.24.1 to Selenium 2.25.0

As the selenium change is just download the jar file and run it instead of the old one,it's worth trying this as a quick and easy troubleshooter - if it doesn't help, just switch back. In your case, I'm not sure which version of Selenium to try, but I think 2.24 should work with FF 10.

Also check the firefox version. It will be better if you turn off the auto update in firefox. So you can avoid version mismatching issues.